# Couch Sync Gateway with OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have a cluster of nodes using OrientDB distributed database and I would like to be possible to make querys against this database with Android terminal using Couchbase Lite. Could be possible make sincronitation using Couch Sync Gateway? I would not like use the OrientDB Http API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a good idea, but AFAIK nobody did it (yet).

Comment: @Lvca and do you think technically it is possible to implement it? Many thanks in advanced

Comment: I don't know the couch sync gateway protocol, sorry. Maybe it could be easier supporting only a subset of API?

Answer (score 0):

The Couchbase Sync Gateway currently can only work against Couchbase Server. Couchbase Lite is just the local NoSQL DB, so probably all of the included sync APIs that are meant to sync with the Sync Gateway would be of little use to you with that OrientDB backend.

Comment: I am working with some methods of the API using Webhooks and integrating then in a OSGI/Karaf nodes with OrientDB databases. Using webhooks it is the only way to read/write from/to OrientDB from CouchSync I think.